# Send Mails asynchronously in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending a mail by using deliver_later method of Action Mailer but it is sending the mail at same time , I get  the response from the controller when the complete action has done, My question is that is there any way to send the mail asynchronously without any gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enqueue the jobs of sending emails. There is a Rails built-in framework called Active Jobs. For more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: `deliver_later` uses ActiveJob to provide asynchronous execution. But in order to get it work as desired, you'll need to add a backend adapter to ActiveJob. If you don't want to use any supported addapter (e.g. DelayedJob, Resque etc.), you'll need to write your own implementaion. See here: http://www.sitepoint.com/dont-get-activejob/